# How can I schedule a task to run on PBT_APMSUSPEND?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, scheduled-tasks

This is a follow-up to [How do I determine logon/logoff times in Windows Powershell without admin rights?](https://superuser.com/questions/1327952/how-do-i-determine-logon-logoff-times-in-windows-powershell-without-admin-rights/1327978#1327978)

I learned recently how to schedule tasks with Windows' Task Scheduler, and I was able to schedule a task that runs on log on and log off events.

However, I incorrectly assumed that putting a laptop to `sleep` would be "folded in" to the `log off` event. Trial of my on-logoff-task shows that it successfully runs when I explicitly lock my laptop (e.g. Win+L), but it does not run when I put my laptop to sleep.

[Scheduling a task before sleep in Windows 7 and hold off the sleep event until task runs](https://superuser.com/questions/573690/scheduling-a-task-before-sleep-in-windows-7-and-hold-off-the-sleep-event-until-t) led me to learn about the `PBT_APMSUSPEND` event, which seems like what I need, but I can't figure out how to select that as my trigger in Task Scheduler. Can a knowledgeable user please advise what I need to do in the `Task Scheduler`/`Edit Trigger` GUI to create a task that runs on the `PBT_APMSUSPEND` event?

[image]

Comment: Dind the event in Event Viewer, right click and attach a Task to this event. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for this event in Event Viewer, and just right click on the event, and select "Attach a Task to this event."
More instructions [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/)